Finding equilibrium points of the three dimensional model
I wanted to find all possible non-zero equilibrium points of the ODE system:
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=rxe^{1-x}-\frac{ax^{2}y}{1+x}\\
    \frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{caxy}{1+x}-\alpha y-\frac{byz}{1+y}\\
    \frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{dbyz}{1+y}-\beta z
\end{cases}
$x(t)$, $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ denote the density of population size of the plant, pest(prey) and predator at a specific time t respectively.
Here the parameters were defined as follows:
r: Growth rate of plant,
a: Interaction rate between plant and pest,
c: Efficiency of pest consumption,
$\alpha$: Death rate of pest,
b: Interaction rate between pest and predator,
d: Efficiency of predator consumption
$\beta$: Death rate of predator.
I could not find all the equilibrium points other than $(0, 0, 0)$.
Kindly help.
I tried using the following code:
eqns = {r*x*Exp[1 - x] - (a*x^2*y)/(1 + x) == 
    0, (c a x y)/(1 + x) - \[Alpha]*y - (b*y*z)/(1 + y) == 
    0, (d b y z)/(1 + y) - \[Beta]*z == 0};
nonNegativityConstraints = {r > 0, a > 0, c > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, b > 0, 
   d > 0, \[Beta] >= 0, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0};


A coarse attempt in the quest for non trivial solutions.
From the last two equations we get
$$
\cases{
y = \frac{\beta}{b d-\beta}\\
z=\frac{d (a c x-\alpha -\alpha  x)}{(x+1) (b d-\beta )}
}
$$
after substitution into the first
$$
x \left(\frac{a \beta  x}{(x+1) (\beta -b d)}+r e^{1-x}\right)=0
$$
now making $x=0$ we have
$$
\{0,\frac{\beta}{b d-\beta},-\frac{\alpha  d}{b d-\beta }\}
$$
which is not feasible so we follow considering now
$$
\frac{a \beta  x}{(x+1) (\beta -b d)}+r e^{1-x}=0
$$
or equivalently
$$
c_1e^x+\frac{x+1}{x}=0
$$
so $c_1$ should be negative: now all depends on the signal of $b d-\beta$, etc.

You can at least show that a solution $x^*$ exists in $(0,1]$ for all $c_1\geq0$ and no solution exists for $c_1<0$. That may be sufficient for some phase space analysis
